# Choosing Features and restoring Features using K Mean in Scikit

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I want to do some K Mean Clustering in Scikit. I have 9 features, but I only want to select four of them in clustering, also since each of four clustering is measured in different metrics, I want to normalize each four feature to be clustered. However, I want to list each data in original form with its respective cluster point. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the original data points.

Either recompute the centroid in the original data, or apply the inverse normalization (z-normalization is reversible!); but then you'll only get data for the four attributes you used.

Recomputing the centroids in the original data is trivial, and will get you information on the other attribute as well (if you can compute a mean, and they aren't e.g. categorial; but then you might want to look at the mode instead)

Comment: if I use 
    preprocessing.scale(). How do I return the scaled data to its original data?

Comment: I don't use scipy much, so I can't give you code. But you may want to look at the *full API* of `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` instead of the *convenience function* `scale` only. From the docs, it has an `inverse_transform` method.